# How to configure HearsayRequireJsBundle with Symfony2 using r.js optimizer?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, requirejs, r.js

There is no working example of using optimized by `r.js` scripts with Symfony2 and [HearsayRequireJsBundle](https://github.com/hearsayit/HearsayRequireJSBundle)

I found only [one example](http://labs.apt.no/how-i-got-the-hearsayrequirejsbundle-working-with-symfony2/) but it works only in `prod` environment.

Here is my code:

Configuration for RequireJs:

```
hearsay_require_js:
    require_js_src: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.min.js
    initialize_template: HearsayRequireJSBundle::initialize.html.twig
    base_url: js
    base_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/scripts
    optimizer:
        path: %kernel.root_dir%/../r.js
        declare_module_name: true
        hide_unoptimized_assets: false
        options:
            name: main
    paths:
        main: @TodoCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/main
```

Main layout code:

```
{% javascripts
    filter='?requirejs'
    '@TodoCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js'
%}
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var require = {
        deps: [],
        callback: function() {
            require(['main'], function() {
            });
        }
    };
</script>
    {{ require_js_initialize({ 'main' : asset_url, 'configure' : false })}}
{% endjavascripts %}
```

File `main.js`:

```
define([
], function(){
    alert(1)
});
```

In `dev` invironment `alert(1)` is triggered, but then `/js/main.js` is loaded with `404` error.

Please help with really working example or advices.